# Why is my counter behind the actual value by 1?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a distributed counter as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) in swift. Here is what I have:

```swift
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("database").document("counter")

    var returnCount = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var counterButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createCounter(ref: db, numShards: 5)
    }
    
    // [START counter_structs]
    @IBAction func counterPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        incrementCounter(ref: db, numShards: 5)
        counterLabel.text = String(getCount(ref: db))
        
    }
    
    // counters/${ID}
    struct Counter {
        let numShards: Int
        
        init(numShards: Int) {
            self.numShards = numShards
        }
    }
    
    // counters/${ID}/shards/${NUM}
    struct Shard {
        let count: Int
        
        init(count: Int) {
            self.count = count
        }
    }
    // [END counter_structs]
    // [START create_counter]
    func createCounter(ref: DocumentReference, numShards: Int) {
        ref.setData(["numShards": numShards]){ (err) in
            for i in 0...numShards {
                ref.collection("shards").document(String(i)).setData(["count": 0])
            }
        }
    }
    // [END create_counter]
    // [START increment_counter]
    func incrementCounter(ref: DocumentReference, numShards: Int) {
        // Select a shard of the counter at random
        let shardId = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numShards)))
        let shardRef = ref.collection("shards").document(String(shardId))
        
        shardRef.updateData([
            "count": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
        ])
    }
    // [END increment_counter]
    // [START get_count]
    func getCount(ref: DocumentReference) -> Int {
        ref.collection("shards").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            var totalCount = 0
            if err != nil {
                print(err ?? "Error")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let count = document.data()["count"] as! Int
                    totalCount += count
                }
            }
            self.returnCount = totalCount
            print(self.returnCount)

        }
        return returnCount
        
    }
    // [END get_count]
}
```

However, when I click the button it is 1 behind what it should be. For example, when I run the app and press the button it displays 0 instead of 1. I think I need some sort of await function but am not sure where it should go or how to implement it. I have tried running it in a dispatch queue but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. Instead of trying to set the label in the `counterPressed` function I set it in the `getCount` function like so:

```swift
func getCount(ref: DocumentReference){
        ref.collection("shards").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            var totalCount = 0
            if err != nil {
                print(err ?? "Error")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let count = document.data()["count"] as! Int
                    totalCount += count
                }
            }
            self.counterLabel.text = String(totalCount)

        }
        
    }
```

and then just call `getCount` in both `viewDidLoad` and `counterPressed`

Comment: This answer is not wrong, but it may become an issue as your database grows. In a nutshell, every time the view loads the documents are read and iterated over. No big deal with 100 but when you have 10,000, that adds up. But then every time a user clicks the counterPressed button, that cycle happens again (slowww). An option is keeping a separate collection/document that stores the count and increment it as documents are added. That way you can remove the iteration code and just read that one document. Additionally, you can add an observer so the UI updates itself when the counter increments.

Comment: @Jay, correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't ```counterPressed``` run in O(n) time? That does not seem overly slow to me.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding. Here's what I see looking at your code - there are two things going on. Given 100,000 documents, when getCount is called 1) All 100,000 documents are loaded with .getDocuments and then 2) every document is iterated over (that's 100,000 iterations) and then 3) the counter label updates. I am fairly sure that won't be very responsive and will become less responsive as the dataset grows. Maybe there's more to it?

Comment: @Jay not quite. ```getCount``` will always only pull down five documents. each of those documents has a field ```count``` which is then added to the total and returned (maybe constant time?).

Comment: Ah - it wasn't clear that you we doing a total of only the shards. Got it. However, in your question you've got a misplaced Return statement. In the `getCount` function you've got `ref.collection("shards").getDocuments() {} return` and that return statement *following* the closure will actually execute *before* the code within the `getDocuments` closure. That may be causing an issue as well.